# How to parse a string of integers only in some range with Parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to learn Parsec by parsing a date string of format "YYYYMMDD", for example "20161030".  And my solution is:

```
date :: Parser (String, String, String)
date = do
  year <- replicateM 4 digit
  month <- replicateM 2 digit
  day <- replicateM 2 digit
  return (year, month, day)
```

But the problem is that "20161356" is also a valid date for my code.

How can I validate the "MM" is between 1 and 12; and "DD" is between 1 and 31?

Comment: `guard $ month >= 0 && month <= 12` ?

Comment: `>=1` maybe? :D

Comment: Side note 20160229 is valid while 20000229 is not, don't foget to check that too

Comment: another side note why is date a `Parser (String, String, String)` and not `String (Integer, Int, Int)` ?? (then @ThomasM.DuBuisson s advice wont work - because you can't compare `String` with `Int` (roughly speaking))

Comment: There is a difference between determining if a string matches a date *format* and determining if a string represents a valid date. A parser should only be responsible for the former.

Comment: @chepner good point - never thought of it that way, but I agree - `parseDate` & `validateDate` should be two separate things

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Int is better.  I chose String just because it's simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `guard` as suggested by Thomas M. DuBuisson:

```
date :: Parser (String, String, String)
date = do
  year <- replicateM 4 digit
  month <- replicateM 2 digit
  day <- replicateM 2 digit
  guard $ read month > 0 && read month <= 12 && read day > 0 && read day <= 31
  return (year, month, day)
```

However, this results in a bad error message:

```
λ> parse date "" "20161356"
Left (line 1, column 9):unknown parse error
```

We can fix this by combining `guard` with `<?>` to provide a better error message:

```
date :: Parser (String, String, String)
date = do
  year <- replicateM 4 digit
  month <- replicateM 2 digit
  guard (read month > 0 && read month <= 12) <?> "valid month (1–12)"
  day <- replicateM 2 digit
  guard (read day > 0 && read day <= 31) <?> "valid day (1–31)"
  return (year, month, day)
```

With this approach, you get a more useful error message:

```
λ> parse date "" "20161356"
Left (line 1, column 7):
expecting valid month (1–12)
```

As a side note, I think it *is* valuable to validate (or at least sanity check) the date in a parser—it ensures that the date validation composes with the rest of your parser and error-handling code. You can't forget to check the date later in your code and the error is localized correctly, which is very useful if you're parsing documents with lots of dates.

Comment: And of course, in real code (as distinct from pedagogical code like displayed here) you should use [`fromGregorianValid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:fromGregorianValid) from the venerable `time` package rather than coding up a simple-but-wrong validator yourself.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yes, although you might also want to do a bit of your own sanity checks to have more detailed error messages.